# My bad questions are holding me to perpetual question bans. Revised

Tags: bug, low-quality-posts, anti-recidivism-system

Everything I tried is in vain. If I ever want to ask a question I will have to open another account and never visit my old account again. This time I'll not make the same mistakes not to ever get banned again.

The below was written in hast. It is another question that is locked in by an answer that doesn't really help me but keeps me from deleting this question thus gaining more down votes.

I wish there was a way to get a full reset without abandoning this one?

I am asking for help is reestablishing my privileges asking questions on SE sites so I ca ask better constructed questions again. Will someone help me decide which questions on Meta can be improved and which are a total loss?

I understand asking which questions I asked are the lowest quality is broad but hopefully I can get direct guidance in specific questions I asked that needs the most revision.

Comment: Maybe you don't realize this but you're asking volunteers to visit each site you have an account on, find your lowest scored question, analyze it's current state and its revision and then write-up a tailored advice for that single post, rinse and repeat. In. Their. Free. Time. At a minimum you could have added the posts that you feel are salvageable (and why) with a bit of help. That would at least teach us what you misinterpreted in all the guidance available to you.

Comment: Don’t even tell us which SE sites you have a question ban on...

Comment: Start with this one ;)

Comment: @rene (s)he is schoolkid, and highly motivated into the sciences. Despite that, his/her posts were handled as if they had been posted by adult, saying not a little bit hypocritically that *"we don't jude users only content"*. His/her posts show clear improvement, but the psychological attacks (s)he got here will be likely lifelong.

Comment: @Helmar Also you know very well, there is no way to get the downvotes back. Of course you won't ever admit it. Btw, there is also no way to "fix" this question, because it is not a bad one, and its voting score says actually more about the voters, as the post.

Comment: Sure @peterh, that is noted. Thanks for your caring. I hope you work out what needs to be done to answer this question because the silence of the OP isn't helping either. And although my comment might come across as harsh, it is left with good intentions. It does explain why I down voted and close voted and it contains the advice on how to improve the question. And yes, I do that in a direct style, but that is me. Get used to it.

Comment: @rene I think the SE should do something with it. The virtual slaps what we can get here, can be serious even for an adult, what will they do with a kid? Can you imagine, how can affect a schoolkid, if he gets a Q/A ban, or even a yearlong suspension, for LQ posts?? The facebook solves the same problem by simply disallowing registrations below an age limit (despite that, kids can still register it, and they do it, but it is already not their responsibility). Maybe we should have an "ask anything" SE site for 18- people, with **much** lenient rules, and their problematic questions should be

Comment: @rene migrated there. Here comes the next problem: first, such a site likely wouldn't survive the A51. It has multiple reasons, the largest is that most of the community, including the high-power decision-makers, simply wouldn't understand the whole concept. The second largest reason is that dealing with kids is a highly dangerous thing from a legal point in the U.S., and the SE would be likely more happy to rather avoid the whole topic et al, and this is what they do.

Comment: @peterh No, I can't imagine that. Maybe I have out grown those feelings.

Comment: @peterh How would we know Muze is a schoolkid - even if we had time to visit https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312109/muze or https://stackexchange.com/users/7224049/muze it does not say that there

Comment: @muze I totally get that it is a sobering experience and that it can take time and effort before posts get recognized by the community as valuable and as a result gets upvoted. And there is no guarantee it works out that way, specially if you do multiple edits that are sub-par, while the community votes on each new revision due to the post being bunped. And I think here on MSE we can give general advice and guidance how to improve your posts but it's much more efficient and effective if you hand pick a couple of posts and explain to us what you want us to advice you on.

Comment: If you make that edit to your post so it gets the much needed focus I'm happy to vote to re-open and ask a couple of others to weigh in. As an alternative you should be able to ask such detailed/focussed question about how to improve a specific question on each site meta. Make sure you put effort in to explain what your interpretation is of guidance in the help and meta (link to it!, show your research,, share an attempt). You get the idea. If you show what you're struggling with and are humble about your mistakes, I'm sure meta will show some love.

Comment: @Muze You really need to read and take action on the things I advice. I said earlier. *Make sure you put effort in to explain what your interpretation is of guidance in the help and meta (link to it!, show your research,, share an attempt)* which is still lacking. You need to make an argument why you think those questions are on-topic and what you're own idea's are to make them a better fit for the sites they are on. You have to do the effort.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at those questions you listed and they all have a smell of being hypothetical, without any practical use or need. While those make interesting questions to tickle the imagination they might not fly well on most of the science sites. I almost feel that WorldBuilding.se might be a better fit for some questions but I personally find that site highly confusing so don't take this as definitive advice. Overall I would say most if not all of your example questions better fit on a forum/discussion site, like Quora or reddit.

Comment: You got some really good answer on those questions, make me wonder why the question ban ai dont check that.

Comment: I'm sorry... "maximum penetration prison"?

Comment: @Muze I tried to contact you, but you didn't react! I could have helped with a lot of tips, tricks, information, advices and so on. Please use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) more often.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Because the SE system has major problems. For example, if a highly downvoted question gets a highly upvoted answer, then this question shouldn't affect into Q ban calculation. Anybody knows this, it is trivial, but nobody will do anything.

Comment: @Muze You registered with a mail address, and you lost that mail address?

Comment: @Muze - If your account was erroneously merged with an account, and you didn't request it, then you should formally request that action be reversed.  Hopefully, you didn't perform actions, to avoid being banned.

Comment: I am avid about doing the right thing here. I brought negative attention to myself to show the system can be improved. None of this is helping me. but maybe it can help countless others who love these subject and SE not to get stuck like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in response to your new addition:

> Everything I tried is in vain. If I ever want to ask a question I will have to open another account and never visit my old account again. This time I'll not make the same mistakes not to ever get banned again.

This is probably not a good idea because trying to get around bans by starting a new account is frowned on.  It's likely that your new account would be identified as being from an older user who was banned and the new account could be suspended or merged into the old one.

If you're willing to take some frank advice:

I've seen your questions on a bunch of SE sites that I read (ones where I don't post much) and I've seen your questions on their metas asking about your questions, your bans, your suspensions.  My overall impression is that :

- You still tend to ask questions that are too broad and conceptual, that tend to be "could this work" or otherwise better suited to a discussion.
- You might be *slowly* getting better, but you're still slow to take feedback and you often ask other people if they can improve your posts - you should be figuring out the improvements yourself.

My suggestions:

Spend some significant time *reading* stuff on the sites you're interested in.  Read the meta on those sites as well.  The best way to figure out what works well on any Internet site is to lurk for a while.

I think your only hope for asking questions is the "one new question after 6 months" loophole.  I don't know where it's explained, but I think that even if you're banned, you can ask one question after 6 months, so you should probably spend the time figuring out what a good question would be to see if you can get some positive response.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you have been post banned on more than one Stack Exchange site, and each post ban is site-specific, and type-specific (questions separate from answers) so you will need to work with a site at a time, if you are to receive help.

Consequently, I think you need to decide which site you wish to seek help with first, and then once you have done what you can to improve your questions, you may (or may not, if the ban applies there too) be able to ask for help on the site-specific meta.

If that fails, then specifying the site you want help with may enable you to get help here.  However, depending on your history, you may find the community you seek help with, may prefer for you to wait out your ban, if you cannot figure out for yourself how to escape it.  My understanding is that it is not hard to get out of a post ban, if you read and follow all advice at:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)

Comment: Just a FYI: the OP edited their question and I re-opened it. You might want to revisit your answer to see if it still fits (at first look it does).

Comment: Thanks @rene - I think I'll leave my answer as-is.  At the minimum I think the asker needs to specify the single site and single question that they seek help with.

Comment: You still seem to be trying to ask for help on multiple questions from multiple sites and have not provided any links to your efforts to try and improve any of them.  To get the Q&A deleted you could try explaining why it should be deleted to SE staff using the Contact button at the bottom of this page.